# Closed equivalence relations and closed equivalence classes.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given a Compact Hausdorff space X and a closed equivalence relation on it, I am trying to show that each equivalence class is a closed subset of X.
I am using the fact that the quotient space of X by this relation is necessarily Hausdorff as the relation is closed. So that by showing that each equivalence class is compact in the quotient space I'd be done, but I don't see how to show this!
Any suggestions? Maybe I am missing something, could you please point me in the right direction?
All help is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't that the definition of a closed equivalence relation? [Here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Closed_equivalence_relation) is my source. Am I oversimplifying this?

Comment: @JohnDouma no, it's also used for the case where $R \subseteq X \times X$ is a closed set (where the latter has the product topology). Willard does this, e.g.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know that $X/{R}$ is Hausdorff then you're almost done: let $q: X \to X/{R}$ be the canonical quotient map sending each $x \in X$ to its class $[x]_R$ under $R$. As $X/{R}$ is Hausdorff, it is $T_1$, i.e. singletons are closed, and by definition every class $[x]_R = q^{-1}[\{q(x)\}]$, which is closed as the inverse image of a closed singleton set under the continuous $q$.